# Inserting Account and custom object record at the same time?

Tags: apex, visualforce, excel

Hi i need to create a record in both Account and custom object"customlead" at the same. I tried this DataLoader but at a time we can select only one object. I need to select both how this could de resloved either by Dataloader or Excel Connector. Can anyone help to solve this issue and tell me the steps.
Thanks,
Regards,
Lavanya.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert records into more than one sObject at a time. All tools (data loader , workbench, excel connector) will only let you insert records into one sObject at a time.

Depending on the use case, you can create an after trigger on Account to create a record in your custom sObject when Account records are inserted.